# Построчное считывание с XmlReader и передача в IDataReader (SqlBulkCopy)

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server

Есть XML большого объема, структура их следующая

```
<Objects>
<Object ID="" name="" level="" .... />
<Object ID="" name="" level="" .... />
```

Мне необходимо их загрузить в БД с помощью `BulkLoad`, хочу построчно передавать их и сразу записывать в потоке.

Читаю XML так -

```
XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("file:////" + PathToFile);
  while (r.Read())
    {
        if ((r.Name == "Object") && (r.HasAttributes))
        {

        }
    }
```

Создал класс который наследуется от `IDataReader`

```
public class CustomObjectDataReader : IDataReader
{
  ...
}
```

Понятно что запись будет происходить примерно так:

```
CustomObjectDataReader reader = new CustomObjectDataReader();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlBulkCopy cpy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
                {
                    cpy.DestinationTableName = "rundom1";
                    cpy.WriteToServer(reader);

                }
            }
```

Проблема в том как считывать построчно в потоке, записывать, и при этом чтобы сохранялось "состояние" `XmlReader`, те мы знали какую строку считали, чтобы не начинать все заново.

Comment: немного не то..

Comment: То, что строчка считалась из XmlReader - еще не означает что она была успешно записана в базу. В качестве защиты "продолжить при ошибке" учет считанных строк не поможет.

Comment: @PashaPash тут записи этой строки нет, я и спрашиваю как это реализовать правильно

Comment: тогда я не понял что вы пытаетесь сделать. вы хотите чтобы за вас кто-то написал код `CustomObjectDataReader`?

Comment: @PashaPash не обязательно,достаточно просто объяснить как это делать и в правильном направлении я двигаюсь или нет

Comment: Хранить `XmlReader` как поле `CustomObjectDataReader`. В CustomObjectDataReader.Read` делать `xmlReader.Read` и вычитывать значения из нового элемента. В методах чтения данных (`Item[]`, `GetXXX`) возвращать значения, вычитанные из `XmlReader` на прошлом `Read` - реализуйте только те методы, которые действительно попытается взывать `WriteToServer`.

Comment: направление - да, правильное.

Comment: @PashaPash а как мне "заморозить" грубо говоря поток XmlReader? Считал одну строку, передал ее на запись, как узнать какая следующая? И надо класс под поля Xml создавать или можно так обойтись?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomObjectDataReader : IDataReader
{
    private XmlReader InnerReader { get; set; }

    public CustomObjectDataReader(string path)
    {
        InnerReader = XmlReader.Create("file:////" + path);
    }

    public object[] CurrentValues { get; set; }

    public bool Read()
    {
        while (this.InnerReader.Read())
        {
            if ((this.InnerReader.Name == "Object") && (this.InnerReader.HasAttributes))
            {
                this.CurrentValues = new object [] {  /* read real values from Inner Reader Here */ }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false; // no more elements to read
    }

    public object this[int i]
    {
        get { return this.CurrentValues[i]; }
    }
}
```

в остальных методах оставить `throw new NotImplementedException();` и реализовать те из них, на которых будет падать при реальнов выполнении, по аналогии с `this[int i]`.

Comment: Спасибо, началось прояснятся немного, буду разбираться

Comment: При реализации упал только метод `FieldCount` - исправил так `get {return 6}` количество атрибутов в моем случае, компилируется без ошибок, но информации нет в БД. Как узнать методы и свойства которые требуют реализации, для корректной работы программы.

Comment: Запустите в отладке, посмотрите, возвращает ли `Read` `true` хоть один раз. Вызывается ли `this[int i]`.

Comment: Возможно я неправильно реализую вот этот момент -`this.CurrentValues = new object [] { InnerReader["ID"], InnerReader["name"] ...  }` и как быть в случае null значений? Возможно из-за этого.

Comment: возможно. проверьте - попробуйте возвращать захардкоженные значения.

Answer (score 1):

Вам по сути нужны сопрограммы. На C# это реализуется при помощи `IEnumerable<T>`-методов.

Например, так:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> ReadXmlObjects()
{
    XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("file:////" + PathToFile);
    while (r.Read())
    {
        if ((r.Name != "Object") || !r.HasAttributes)
            continue;
        using (var sub = xmlReader.ReadSubtree())
            yield return XElement.Load(sub);
    }
}
```

Теперь, вам нужен кастомный `IDataReader`. Можно сделать что-то такое:

```
class CustomDataReader : IDataReader
{
    IEnumerator<XElement> it;

    // добавьте сюда что нужно
    static List<string> indexToName = new List<string> { "ID", "level" };

    public CustomDataReader(IEnumerable<XElement> seq)
    {
        it = seq.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Read() { return it.MoveNext(); }
    public int FieldCount
    {
        get { return indexToName.Count; }
    }

    XAttribute GetCurrAttribute(int i)
    {
        return it.Current.Attributes(indexToName[i]).Single();
    }

    public byte GetByte(int i)
    {
        return (byte)GetCurrAttribute(i);
    }

    public char GetChar(int i)
    {
        return (char)GetCurrAttribute(i);
    }

    // и т. д.

    public string GetName(int i)
    {
        return indexToName[i];
    }

    public void Close() { it.Dispose(); }
    public void Dispose() { Close(); }
}
```

Comment: А почему `((r.Name != "Object") || !r.HasAttributes)` если нам наоборот надо считывать оттуда информацию?

Comment: @e1s: Ну там же следующей строчкой идёт `continue`.